# Terraform recreating aws_iam_access_key each time

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform

I have a Terraform module which creates a user for my CI environment to publish to ECR.

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "continuous-deployment" {
  name = "continuous-deployment"
  path = "/system/"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "continuous-deployment" {
  user    = "${aws_iam_user.continuous-deployment.name}"
  pgp_key = "${var.pgp_key}"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "continuous-deployment" {
  name = "continuous-deployment"
  user = "${aws_iam_user.continuous-deployment.name}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
          "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
          "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
          "ecr:ListImages",
          "ecr:DescribeImages",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
          "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
          "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
          "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
          "ecr:PutImage",
          "ecr:GetLoginToken"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

output "aws_access_key_id" {
  value = "${aws_iam_access_key.continuous-deployment.id}"
}

output "aws_secret_access_key" {
  value = "${aws_iam_access_key.continuous-deployment.encrypted_secret}"
}
```

The issue I am having is that on each `terraform apply`, Terraform wants to delete and recreate these resources even when they have not changed.

I have no idea why this is happening and can't find anyone in a similar position unfortunately. Ideas?

Comment: `terraform plan` should show why it wants to delete and re-create resources.

Comment: Once your policy is created, copy the content exactly like it appears in AWS web console and paste in your script

Answer (score 0):

This happens, mostly in some IAM policies or s3 policies definition.

When run with `terraform plan/apply`, it exports that some resources need be re-created, and list the policy changes in one line, that you can't easily identify the changes.

Please use [terraform-landscape](https://github.com/coinbase/terraform-landscape) to redirect the terraform plan output to it, and get nicely sorted output.  Then you should easily identify which part need be fixed.

```
gem install terraform_landscape

terraform plan ... | landscape
```